# Can't access internet using a domain joined computer outside the domain environment

Tags: windows, windows-xp, domain

We had an unused computer at work, so I took it home. It had been joined to the domain and hasn't been unjoined. When I try to use it at home (logging in with a local admin account) I can't seem to access Internet pages.

It gets the correct IP address and gateway for the local network and correct DNS servers for the home ADSL connection.

I can happily ping the home router (which doesn't have any tricky firewall settings). I can't seem to ping outside, get any DNS to resolve, or (obviously) get any web pages. Is there some problem here with this having been joined to the domain?

Comment: Can you ping an address by IP? e.g. 74.125.230.114

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you get an IP address and can ping the router, means your network is up. If you cannot get outside the network, then likely your LAN settings are configured to go through a proxy, probably a left-over configuration from when on the domain.

First make sure you are not on the domain anymore: Right Mouse Button `My Computer`, Properties, on the "Computer Name" tab click the "Change" button to 'rename this computer or join a domain', and check it is on a workgroup, and not on the old domain:

[image]

Then make sure you don't try connect via a proxy (some domains have this setup). From Control Panel access Internet Properties, on the Connections tab, in the LAN settings check you are not connecting via an old proxy (from the previous domain setup).'

[image]

Comment: Excellent glad that worked :-)

Comment: I know this is old, but this totally saved me. I was fiddling with settings and such for nearly an hour before I saw this and figured out what was up. For me though, I needed to CHECK "use automatic configuration script" to use the address that was already populated for my domain's proxy server.